# Кастомный View с плавным двусторонним скроллингом и эффектом флинга как в WebVew

Tags: android, прокрутка, android-customview

Всем привет! Пишу кастомный `View`, наследованный от `RelativeLayout`, в него динамически добавляются `View` элементы. При его создании я устанавливаю минимальную ширину и высоту в зависимости от ширины и высоты экрана.

Решил добавить возможность прокрутки, для этого обернул кастомную `View` в `HorizontalScrollView`, а его - в `ScrollView`. Но прокрутки не были одновременными, тоесть скроллить можно было только в одну сторону. Тогда я создал кастомные `ScrollView` и `HorizontalScrollView` в которых переопределил `onTouchEvent`, возвращая `false`. Тогда `onTouchEvent` я реализовал в активности. В нем я скроллил `HorizontalScrollView` и `ScrollView` одновременно. Но тогда прокрутка не была идеальной. При отпускании пальца скроллинг останавливался. А нужен был эффект прокрутки например как в списке, чтобы при отпускании пальца при быстром скролле он продолжался, но затухал.

Нашел [эту](http://apsoid.ru.u12447.stark.vps-private.net/talk/topic/527-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8/) статью. Сделал все как по ней, правда долго не понимал что такое скроллер. Итог: упущен день, ничего не скроллится и я решил попросить помощи у профессионалов.

**Кастомный View**

```
public class MetroMapView extends RelativeLayout
{
Context ctx;
List<Station> list;
LayoutInflater inflater;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
List<View> stations;
Paint line;
public Scroller scroller;
int mapWidth, mapHeight;
VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
int oldX = -1, oldY = -1;
int dx = 0, dy = 0;

public MetroMapView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(ctx, attrs);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    scroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    line = new Paint();
    line.setStrokeWidth(10);
    line.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    line.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    stations = new ArrayList<>();
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((GameActivity)ctx).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    //ширина и высота карты
    mapWidth = metrics.widthPixels * 3;
    mapHeight = metrics.heightPixels * 2;

    //установка размеров
    setMinimumHeight(mapHeight);
    setMinimumWidth(mapWidth);
}

void setElements(ArrayList<Station> list)
{
    this.list = list;
    //перебираем все станции
    for(Station s : list)
    {
        //инфлэйт
        View station = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_view, null);

        //установка id и координат
        station.setId(View.generateViewId());
        station.setX(s.getX());
        station.setY(s.getY());

        //добавляем станцию в RelativeLayout
        addView(station);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(list != null)
    {
        for(Station s : list)
        {
            if(s.getAnchorX() != 0 && s.getAnchorY() != 0)
            {
                float fromX = s.getX() + 25;
                float fromY = s.getY() + 25;
                float toX = s.getAnchorX() + 25;
                float toY = s.getAnchorY() + 25;
                canvas.drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, line);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                oldX = (int) ev.getX();
                oldY = (int) ev.getY();
                return true;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
                int deltaX = (int) (oldX - ev.getX());
                int deltaY = (int) (oldY - ev.getY());
                oldX = (int) ev.getX();
                oldY = (int) ev.getY();
                //yScroll.scrollBy(deltaX, deltaY);
                //xScroll.scrollBy(deltaX, deltaY);
                scroller = new Scroller(getContext());
                scroller.startScroll(dx, dy, -deltaX, -deltaY);
                return true;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                int vx = (int) mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                int vy = (int) mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity();
                vx = vx * 3 / 4;
                vy = vy * 3 / 4;
                scroller = new Scroller(getContext());
                scroller.fling(dx, dy, vx, vy, 0, 1500, 0, 1500);
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                return true;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**Разметка**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--<ru.albatros.metropolis.VScroll
    android:id="@+id/yScroller"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ru.albatros.metropolis.HScroll
        android:id="@+id/xScroller"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
-->
        <ru.albatros.metropolis.MetroMapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#527dad"/>

    <!--</ru.albatros.metropolis.HScroll>

</ru.albatros.metropolis.VScroll>
-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Неужели нет библиотеки?

Comment: В данный момент я перерес весь код `ScrollView` себе и планирую создать кастомный виджет, обьединив его логику с `HorizontalScrollView`. Правда скролл пока не работает

Comment: Скролл до сих пор не работает. Стоит ли дальше пытаться подружить `ScrollView` с `HorizontalScrollView`? Или можно их по отдельности заставить работать как надо? Очень неудобно скроллить карту по одному направлению или без эффекта флинга

Comment: В `WebView` исходниках не нашел что там у него скроллится

Comment: вот это видели? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19411644/1654690 по мне хорошее решение

Comment: @Flippy, было б круто если б тут где-то появилась ссылка на видео/гифку с результатом)

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, я сейчас начал разработку своего первого кастомного вью, в данный момент сделал так, что любой `View` можно обернуть в кастом вью и не париться, в планах сделать программный скролл по двум осям, установка слушателей всяких также по двум осям, еще куча работы :) я на гитхабе вообще новичок, не знаю, можно ли оставить ссылку на aar?
Чтобы в libs его кидать для подключения? А то с gradle/maven никак не разберусь)) кстати, можете следить  за работой)) когда появитс чтото помимо скролла, сделаю гифку, тогда и посмотрите https://github.com/ATumbler/VerticalHorizontalScrollView

Comment: @Flippy, будет круто, если допилите - мне б такая либа очень б не помешала) Я бы и просто на скролл бы посмотрел)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, о, круто ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну допустим у Вас был код, когда вы оборачивали контентную `View` в `HorizontalScrollView`, а его в `ScrollView`.

Можно попробовать при инициализации `HorizontalScrollView` и `ScrollView`, установить им Smooth Scrolling:

```
mHorisontalScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
mScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Как вариант, Вам лучше бы создать кастомный `TouchHostView`, унаследованный допустим от `FrameLayout`, в который вы и поместите весь, уже созданный агрегат :)

Должен получиться `TouchHostView`, внутри которого `ScrollView`, внутри которого `HorizontalScrollView`, внутри которого Ваша кастомная `View`.

После этого переопределить метод `dispatchTouchEvent` у `TouchHostView` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean dispatch = mCustomView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    if (!dispatch) {
        dispatch = mHorisontalScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        dispatch |= mScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return dispatch;
}
```

В теории это должно помочь Вам :)

Примерно так должен выглядеть `TouchHostView`:

```
public class TouchHostView extends FrameLayout {

    private View mHorizontalScrollView;
    private View mScrollView;
    private View mCustomView;

    public TouchHostView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate();
    }

    public TouchHostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate();
    }

    public TouchHostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflate();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TouchHostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, 
                         int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        inflate();
    }

    private void inflate() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.touch_host, this, true);

        mHorisontalSrollView = findViewById(R.id.h_scroll);
        mScrollView = findViewById(R.id.v_scroll);
        mCustomView = findViewById(R.id.custom);

        ((HorizontalScrollView) mHorizontalScrollView)
                .setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
        ((ScrollView) mScrollView).setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean dispatch = mCustomView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if (!dispatch) {
            dispatch = mHorisontalScrollView.onTouchEvent(ev);
            dispatch |= mScrollView.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        return dispatch;
    }
}
```

А его разметка примерно так:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView>

        <HorizontalScrollView>

            <CustomView/>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

</merge>
```

Comment: Тоесть `dispatchTouchEvent` отправит скроллерам `MotionEvent` и они будут одновременно работать?

Comment: ну как-то так, если Вы хотите, чтобы они работали одновременно, то надо им обоим отсылать пришедшее событие)

Comment: Ага. Понятно. А по умолчанию выходит отправляется кому?

Comment: Эта тема достойная отдельной статьи :) Если вкратце, то dispatch идёт сначала от корневого Layout к верхней сфокусированной View, после чего назад тем же путём. Если View обработала событие, она обязана ответить true. Если она сказала false, то каждый последующий элемент, которому приходит false имеет право обработать событие самостоятельно, после чего при обработке также шлёт true, иначе false.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас проверю :)

Comment: А как мне получить скроллеры из `TouchHostView`? `childAt`?

Comment: Забыл про Smooth Scroll в коде, добавил, обновил :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57607/discussion-between-flippy-and-artilirium).